# Why is my php $_POST and $_SESSION not clearing after each run of my log-in sequence?

Tags: php, mysql, phpstorm

FYI: This is homework so I cannot post all the code.

I am on Ubuntu 18.04 using PhpStorm in debug mode and just to make sure, I have added

```
$_POST = array();
$_SESSION = array();
```

to clear out those arrays at the end of the landing page called `view_mainpage.php` when sign in is successful and also in the `controller.php` right before `exit()` is called.

I have a switch statement in `controller.php` for join or signin.  The signin half of it looks like this:

```
switch ($command) {  // When a command is sent from the client
        case 'SignIn':  // With username and password
            if (user_exists($username)== false) {//user does not exist
                something_wrong();
            }
            else { //user exists validate entries first
                if((check_username()!='ok') || (check_password()!='ok')){
                    something_wrong();
                }
                else{//all entries are well formatted
                    //set valid_username
                    $valid_username = $username;
                    $_SESSION['valid_user'] = $valid_username;
                    //validate existing user
                    if(validate_existing_user($username, $password)==false){
                        something_wrong();//row with username, pass not found
                    }
                    else {
                        //get user id
                        $user_id = get_user_id($username);
                        if($user_id!=-1){
                            include('w4_view_mainpage.php');
                        }

                    }
                }

            }
            $_POST = array();
            $_SESSION = array();
            exit();
```

At the top of controller.php, it handles the first time it lands on `controller.php` like this:

```
<?php
//When controller.php is accessed for the first time
if(!isset($_SESSION)){
    session_start();
}
if (empty($_POST['page'])) {
    $d_type = 'none';
    //$_SESSION['display_type'] = $d_type;
    include ('w4_view_startpage.php');
    exit();
}

/*
*   When commands come from StartPage or MainPage meaning it's not the first time we landed
on controller.php so it goes to the switch statement.
*/

require ('model.php');  // connect to MySQL database; functions to access DB tables

// When commands come from StartPage
if ($_POST['page'] == 'StartPage') {
    $command = $_POST['command'];
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $email='';
    if(!empty($_POST['email'])){
        $email = $_POST['email'];
    }
.
.
.
```

I included some more code and comments to show how the sign-in/join flows.

- So the very first time it is redirected to `view_startpage.php` that has a little clickable menu and popup modal windows for either join or signin.
- On successful "join" the user is redirected to `view_startpage.php` but on successful signin gets redirected to `view_mainpage.php` where as mentioned above I clear out post and session.
- But when I refresh the page in Firefox and refresh on PhpStorm, `$_POST` and `$_REQUEST` already have elements for `page`, `command`, `username`, `password` from the previous signin so I can never get back to view_startpage.php, it just reloads the `view_mainpage.php`.

I've tried invalidating caches and restarting but it doesn't always work.  This one time right before writing this it did.

The connection to MySQL, and my functions in `model.php` all seem to be working so I have no idea what I can do to 'start fresh` each time.

Edit:  Addressing some questions in comments below.

1. `$username`, `$password` and `$email` are submitted via a form on startpage.php.

```
<form method='post' action='w4_controller.php'>
                <input type='hidden' name='page' value='StartPage'>
                <input type='hidden' name='command' value='SignIn'>
                <label class='modal-label'>Username:</label>
                <input type='text' name='username' required>
                <span id="username-error">
                    <?php
                    ...left out php as it is the homework. basically inline error messages when input is invalid
                    }?>

                </span>
                <br>
                <br>
                <label class='modal-label'>Password:</label>
                <input type='password' name='password' required>
                <span id="password-error">
                    <?php
                    ...left out php per above
                    }?>

                </span>
                <br>
                <br>
                <input type='submit'>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <input id='cancel-signin-button' type='button' value='Cancel'>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <input type='reset'>
            </form>
```

Comment: I don't see the point of using sessions if you empty the session variable at the end of the script? Sessions are used to keep data between requests so emptying it at the end of the script/request kind of defeats the purpose. Or do `something_wrong()` redirect the user?

Comment: You should also post all relevant code, like what any of those "magic variables" like `$username`, `$password` comes from, the form, how you send the data (ajax or just ordinary form submission?) It would be nice with a "step by step" guide how you reproduce the issue. It's a bit unclear at the moment. We can help better if we have a broader view. Also, is this just an issue when debugging in PHPStorm or do you have the same issue when testing through a browser (without PHPStorm involved at all)?

Comment: Without PHPStorm, my code works.  I ran it via terminal on VSCode on a LEMP stack (Nginx, MySQL) with no problems.  I set up X-debug on PHPStorm and I see that it uses cookies so does that have to do with it or is the answer by amit177 correct?

Answer (score 2):

```
$_POST = array();
```

Clearing out the array doesn't actually clear it on the client-side, only on the server-side - your end.

What you need to do is redirect the user to the same page ([Location header](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)), that way the request will be changed from a POST to a GET, and the previous information wouldn't be sent when the client refreshes the page.

Ex:

```
header("Location: ".$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);
exit();
```

Comment: can you put a small snippet as an example for your answer?

Comment: added, not completely sure how useful it would be tho. P.S. Mangus is correct as well, there's no point to use sessions if you load it once and then delete all data. You might want to consider changing how your flow works. ex, instead of loading the page in the SignIn part, redirect to a different page that has the check for it (or the same page and then load that using the session). obviously this is just an example, there are a lot of ways to make it work.

Comment: you mean a landing page that checks if all the log-in info is correct again?

Comment: yeah pretty much. if the user has a valid session (logged in), load the main page/dashboard. otherwise, load the login page.
if you are comfortable enough, you could make it different files as well. ex, login.php for logins and index.php for the landing page (or anything else).

Comment: That sounds right, I'm doing that for my Flask app but this PHP is for weekly school assignments so I was getting lazy but I guess I should do everything the right way.

Comment: It would look a lot cleaner and should get you a better grade as well :)